# Google Maps: localizar algún lugar por un nombre

Tags: android, google-maps

Quisiera saber como podría hacer para realizar una búsqueda en google maps mediante un botón o algo, es decir:

Mi aplicación para fotógrafos necesita que al pulsar un botón aparezca una pantalla con GoogleMaps y localize Sams Club, laboratorios de fotografía y sitios de taxi, pero no encuentro información acerca de cómo hacer esto. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea? La estoy haciendo en android studio.

Comment: Para hacer lo que quieres, tienes que usar la api de google places, te dejo un enlace: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/?hl=es Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, la clase [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=es) tiene un método que se llama 
*getFromLocationName* con el que puedes buscar una localización a partir de un nombre:

```
 Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(context);
 int maxResultados = 1;
 List<Address> adress = geo.getFromLocationName("nombreLugarQueQuieroBuscar", maxResultados);
 LatLng latLng = new LatLng(adress.get(0).getLatitude(), adress.get(0).getLongitude());
```